# Optimization in Scipy

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize

I want to add some constraints to the following code in which I want to optimize the output using scipy.

```
    """
References:
    https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html
    https://github.com/DTUWindEnergy/PyWake
"""


import time

from py_wake.examples.data.hornsrev1 import V80 
from py_wake.examples.data.hornsrev1 import Hornsrev1Site # We work with the Horns Rev 1 site, which comes already set up with PyWake.
from py_wake import BastankhahGaussian

from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np


def funC(x, y, c):
    """
    Turns on/off the use of wind turbine depending on the value of c.
    scipy generates c real values in the range [0, 1] as specified by the bounds including 0.2 etc.
    If c is 0.5 or more turbine will be used otherwise turbine will not be used.
    """
    x_selected = x[c >= 0.5]
    y_selected = y[c >= 0.5]
    
    return (x_selected, y_selected)


def wt_simulation(c):
    """
    This is our objective function. It will return the aep=annual energy production in GWh.
    We will maximize aep.
    """
    site = Hornsrev1Site()
    x, y = site.initial_position.T
    windTurbines = V80()
    
    wf_model = BastankhahGaussian(site, windTurbines)
    x_new, y_new = funC(x, y, c)

    # run wind farm simulation
    sim_res = wf_model(
        x_new, y_new, # wind turbine positions
        h=None, # wind turbine heights (defaults to the heights defined in windTurbines)
        type=0, # Wind turbine types
        wd=None, # Wind direction (defaults to site.default_wd (0,1,...,360 if not overriden))
        ws=None, # Wind speed (defaults to site.default_ws (3,4,...,25m/s if not overriden))
    )
    
    aep_output = sim_res.aep().sum()  # we maximize aep
    
    return -float(aep_output)  # negate because of scipy minimize


def solve():
    t0 = time.perf_counter()
    
    wt = 80  # for V80

    x0 = np.ones(wt)  # initial value
    bounds = [(0, 1) for _ in range(wt)]

    res = minimize(wt_simulation, x0=x0, bounds=bounds)
    
    print(f'success status: {res.success}')
    print(f'aep: {-res.fun}')  # negate to get the true maximum aep
    print(f'c values: {res.x}\n')

    print(f'elapse: {round(time.perf_counter() - t0)}s')  


# start
solve()
```

now I want to add a constraint in which turbulence intensity: `sim_res_TI_eff` of each wind turbine(wt) for each wind speed(was) and each wind direction(wd) must be lower than a certain value(for instance 0.2). I have to add that `sim_res.TI_eff.sel(wt=1)` for instance gives the TI of each wd and was of wind turbine #1. The problem is that I need to use the function wt_simulation in which I have another return that must be optimized so I do not know how can return TI which does not be affected by optimization.

Comment: This ti_eff is only available after the simulation. We cannot input ti_eff before simulation. And our objective is max aep. It seems to me that scipy cannot do this. But optuna hyperparameter tuner can. The idea is we simulate first, then get the ti_eff for all turbines, if there is even one turbine that has a ti_eff of 0.2 and above we tell optuna that aep is zero this way it will try to find max aep where ti_eff for all turbines are below 0.2.

Comment: If you have a simulation step in the function evaluation, you need to restrict solvers to be of the class "Derivative-Free Optimization" (DFO). Doing finite differences is *not* a good idea.

Comment: @ferdy so you mean I have to use Optuna for this type of constraint? if yes, in each iteration after the simulation if TI will be greater than 0.2, it makes the aep for that wt=0 so c for that specific wt must be changed to 0 and it will be as an initial guess for the next iteration(c(wt=i)=0).  but can do optuna do this?

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen can you explain it a bit? since I have not much experience in programming and optimization so some concepts are new

Comment: Using simulation you don't get gradients. Most nonlinear solvers depend on gradients. If not available that may use finite differences to approximate them. This assumes that function evaluations are cheap. In the case of simulation, this is not the case. So DFO solvers are the type of solvers to use: they don't require gradients, and they don't do finite differences. A good reference is: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%252Fs10898-012-9951-y. I don't completely understand your constraint. It helps (a lot) to formulate a mathematical model first.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen indeed I am optimizing the power output of a wind farm, by switching off some turbines( indeed due to limitation I must switch off some turbines so so I want to optimize plant after switching off them) but I want to add one constraint in which if the variable=Turbulence in a wind turbine will be greater than a specific value then that wind turbine will be switched off(it is one limitation). But the problem is that sim_res.TI_eff, which gives the Turbulence, is obtained after the simulation result. So I do not know how I can investigate this constraint?

Comment: A quick way (not necessarily the best) would be to forbid such a pattern: just return a large negative value for output. The solver will try to find a different configuration. But: I would use a solver that supports binary variables (to turn on or off turbines). Python optimize is not the state-of-the-art in optimization, to put it mildly.

Comment: c is not affected because it is an input param, before simulation we can already define c. After some research you can still use scipy. You can compare its performance against hyperparameter optimizers like [optuna](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), [nevergrad](https://github.com/facebookresearch/nevergrad) and others. By the way I did test the given model and its ti_eff is always 0.1. Since we can know the ti_eff value for the given model then this is not needed. It is better to optimize the input param in site and turbine classes, like building a generic wind turbine.

Comment: @ferdy aha, I got it; as the last question, what about the c? is it possible to define a constraint for instance in which for example the value of c[1]=0 ( I mean the wt number 1 must be switched off) or something like this.

Comment: One way of not using a turbine is by setting ws=0, with speed at zero specific wt will not generate power. ws[0]=0, ws[5]=0 that will disable wt0 and wt5, Check what will happen to simulation results. Also have a look at the documentation, there can be other ways to disable a wt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach in dealing with ti_eff.

```
"""
References:
    https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html
    https://github.com/DTUWindEnergy/PyWake
"""


import time

from py_wake.examples.data.hornsrev1 import V80 
from py_wake.examples.data.hornsrev1 import Hornsrev1Site # We work with the Horns Rev 1 site, which comes already set up with PyWake.
from py_wake import BastankhahGaussian

from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np


TIEFF_THRESHOLD = 0.2


def ok_tieff_constraint(tieff):
    """
    Returns True if tieff is below threshold otherwise False.
    """
    if np.any(tieff >= TIEFF_THRESHOLD):
        return False
    return True


def funC(x, y, c):
    """
    Turns on/off the use of wind turbine depending on the value of c.
    scipy generates c real values in the range [0, 1] as specified by the bounds including 0.2 etc.
    If c is 0.5 or more turbine will be used otherwise turbine will not be used.
    """
    x_selected = x[c >= 0.5]
    y_selected = y[c >= 0.5]
    
    return (x_selected, y_selected)


def wt_simulation(c):
    """
    This is our objective function. It will return the aep=annual energy production in GWh.
    We will maximize aep.
    """
    islogging = True
    site = Hornsrev1Site()
    x, y = site.initial_position.T
    windTurbines = V80()
    
    wf_model = BastankhahGaussian(site, windTurbines)
    x_new, y_new = funC(x, y, c)

    # run wind farm simulation
    sim_res = wf_model(
        x_new, y_new, # wind turbine positions
        h=None, # wind turbine heights (defaults to the heights defined in windTurbines)
        type=0, # Wind turbine types
        wd=None, # Wind direction (defaults to site.default_wd (0,1,...,360 if not overriden))
        ws=None, # Wind speed (defaults to site.default_ws (3,4,...,25m/s if not overriden))
    )
    
    if islogging:
        print(sim_res)
    
    aep_output = float(sim_res.aep().sum())  # we maximize aep
    
    # Constraint on ti_eff, if constraint is violated we set aep to zero.
    if not ok_tieff_constraint(sim_res.TI_eff):
        aep_output = 0
    
    return -aep_output  # negate because of scipy minimize


def solve():
    t0 = time.perf_counter()
    
    wt = 80  # for V80

    x0 = np.ones(wt)  # initial value
    bounds = [(0, 1) for _ in range(wt)]

    res = minimize(wt_simulation, x0=x0, bounds=bounds)
    
    print(f'success status: {res.success}')
    print(f'aep: {-res.fun}')  # negate to get the true maximum aep
    print(f'c values: {res.x}\n')

    print(f'elapse: {round(time.perf_counter() - t0)}s')  


# start
solve()
```

Output:

```
...

<xarray.SimulationResult>
Dimensions:           (wt: 80, wd: 360, ws: 23)
Coordinates:
  * wt                (wt) int32 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ... 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79
  * wd                (wd) int32 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ... 353 354 355 356 357 358 359
  * ws                (ws) int32 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ... 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
    x                 (wt) float64 4.24e+05 4.24e+05 ... 4.294e+05 4.295e+05
    y                 (wt) float64 6.151e+06 6.151e+06 ... 6.148e+06 6.148e+06
    h                 (wt) float64 70.0 70.0 70.0 70.0 ... 70.0 70.0 70.0 70.0
    type              (wt) int32 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Data variables: (12/15)
    WS_eff            (wt, wd, ws) float64 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 ... 22.87 23.88 24.89
    TI_eff            (wt, wd, ws) float64 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 ... 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1
    Power             (wt, wd, ws) float64 0.0 6.66e+04 1.54e+05 ... 2e+06 2e+06
    CT                (wt, wd, ws) float64 0.0 0.818 0.806 ... 0.06084 0.05377
    WS                (ws) int32 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ... 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
    WD                (wd) int32 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ... 353 354 355 356 357 358 359
    ...                ...
    Weibull_A         (wd) float64 9.177 9.177 9.177 9.177 ... 9.177 9.177 9.177
    Weibull_k         (wd) float64 2.393 2.393 2.393 2.393 ... 2.393 2.393 2.393
    Sector_frequency  (wd) float64 0.001199 0.001199 ... 0.001199 0.001199
    P                 (wd, ws) float64 6.147e-05 8.559e-05 ... 2.193e-08
    tilt              (wt, wd, ws) float64 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
    yaw               (wt, wd, ws) float64 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
Attributes:
    wd_bin_size:  1
success status: True
aep: 682.0407252944838
c values: [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]

elapse: 273s
```